# Why is the Bitwise OR operator being used in a variable declaration?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and reading through the documentation but I'm confused why the bitwise OR operator is being used in the `product` variable declaration below. What does the `product: Product | undefined` line mean?

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product: Product | undefined;
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context it is not the OR operator but a "Union Type".

> In TypeScript, a union type variable is a variable which can store
> multiple type of values (i.e. number, string etc).
>
> A union type allows us to define a variable with multiple types. The
> union type variables are defined using the pipe ('|') symbol between
> the types.

Source: https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/union-types/

So this means that product must be of type `Product` or `undefined`. (the undefined part is only relevant if you have `strictNullChecks` enabled).

Another way to write this is

```
product?: Product;
```

Where the question mark indicates that it is an optional parameter.

Comment: Just a note/caution: The "alternate form" you provided is not strictly equivalent. In the OP's code, the property will definitely be present, having a value of type `Product` or `undefined`. In your alternate form, the property might be present and having one of the previously mentioned values, or not be present at all. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes